# How to make the signature be saved on the server in a png file?

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, signaturepad, jsignature

How to make the signature be saved on the server in a png file, I want to make the signature save in a png file, I need it as a photo because I'm using it to create a contract.

I tried gptchat help but unfortunately it doesn't work well. And that is my "saveing code" but doesn't work properly, when I try to open a photo I get the message "the format is currently not supported or the file is corrupted"

```
$folderPath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/podpis/";
    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $podpis); 
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $file = $folderPath .'signature_'.$imie_nazwisko.'_'.$data1.'.png';
    $image = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($image_parts[0]));
imagepng($image, $file);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: Sorry, but we do not offer help for code generated by chatGPT. Reason is that it does not work. It is not our task to fix that. Sorry.

Comment: its not code generated by chatGPT, i found that 2 weeks ago and i can't remember where, that was something like blog, I tried to get chatgpt help but nothing change

Comment: I'm fairly certain you should be using the `1` index instead of `0` in this line: `imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($image_parts[0]))`; Whenever you write code, avoid chaining a bunch of commands together until you are confident they are correct. Also, `var_dump` is your friend, and avoid `echo` for all debugging. https://3v4l.org/OOdN3

Comment: I changed 0 to 1 but I get an error undefined offset, my $podpis variable receives form data from another file
$podpis=$_POST['signature_data']; and this is what my canvas tag looks like    <canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad" name="signature-pad"><input type="hidden" id="signature_data" name="signature_data"> </canvas>

Comment: i found thing like that on szimek github $data_uri = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...";
$encoded_image = explode(",", $data_uri)[1];
$decoded_image = base64_decode($encoded_image);
file_put_contents("signature.png", $decoded_image); i change my code into this and file is generating but still it's say the format is currently not supported, i checked correctness of coding on base64encode.org and that's the results : pngbase64iVBORw0 i don't know its good or no good